# Setting the timeout for an Azure Data Factory Linked Service type SAP Table connection

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline activity set up with a [SAP Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties) as Source, and an Azure SQL database as Sink. I have defined partitions to load SAP table data in chunks.

When I run the pipeline, some partitions fail due to a timeout error connecting to our SAP instance.

I want to know where I can set the timeout value, as to give the ADF runtime more time to connect. Does anyone know where to set this property?

I have looked in all the linked service options, but as of yet haven't found out where this setting can be found. There is an Activity timeout setting set to the default 12hrs, which doesn't seem to be the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Does the timeout error comes from data factory, of from SAP?

Comment: The error msg is too long to post, here's a part:

Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,''Type=SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException,Message=
LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host NLVFS01 with Unicode
ERROR partner 'NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:3302' not reached
TIME Mon Feb 20 12:02:24 2023
RELEASE 721
COMPONENT NI (network interface)
VERSION 40
RC -10
MODULE nixxi.cpp
LINE 3289
DETAIL NiPConnect2: NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:3302
SYSTEM CALL connect
ERRNO 10060
ERRNO TEXT WSAETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out
COUNTER 2

RETURN CODE: 20,Source=sapnco_utils,

Comment: The error is shown in the pipeline run which fails.